# Cross domain session for multilingual site hosted on different server

Tags: php, session, cookies, subdomain

I have 2 sub-domain for a multilingual site (Arabic and English), 1 subdomain is on a different server.

```
member.example.com for centralizer login on SERVER1
video.example.com for videos on another server SERVER2
```

I use:

```
session_name('example');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');
session_start();
```

All session data is available on both sub-domain but the issue is LANGUAGE.

If user open video.example.com and change language to ARABIC and visit member.example.com he will see member.example.com pages in English. Although he comes from ARABIC interface.

Any Suggestions to resolve this issue, Thanks.

I use Session to store Language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how your storing your session data. In PHP, by default, the data is stored in a file on the local machine. That means that on each machine, the user will have a unique, distinct session file. In order for the session data to truly persist across both machines, they need to be stored in a 3rd location. This could be a Memcached server, a database, etc. That way, when the session is changed in one location, it's changed universally for all servers accessing the session data.

You can check out the php session handler page for more info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

You can also find info about using Memcached as your session handler here: http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.sessions.php

With PHP it's very easy to roll your own as well. I wrote my own to store data in a SQL Server database to handle things behind my load balancer. Works like a charm.

Comment: ok agreed, but server administartor was unable to configure memcache, so i use curl call  with session data for authentication on domain hosted on other server to avail session data there. As you understand the question, when a session value changed on 2nd subdomain it not updated universally. Thanks for your response, Any quick suggestion to handle it? in current circumstances.